# Cannot get data from file

Tags: java, io, file-handling, randomaccessfile, eofexception

Using `JFileChooser` to save file and everything works perfect:

```
private void saveFileDialog(){

    fileChooser = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("employees.dat"));
    disableTextField(fileChooser.getComponents());

    fileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File("employees.dat"));
    fileChooser.setDialogTitle("File to save");

    int userSelection = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
    if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File fileToSave = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        save();
        System.out.println("Save as file: " + fileToSave.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Calling method  `save()`:

```
public void save(){
    RandomAccessFile file = null;
    try {
        file = new  RandomAccessFile("employees.dat", "rw");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     try{
         for(Employee em: list){
      if(list != null){

        file.writeUTF(em.getPps());
        file.writeUTF(em.getName());
        file.writeUTF(em.getSurname());
        file.writeUTF(em.getGender());
        file.writeUTF(em.getDep());
        file.writeInt(em.getSalary());
        file.writeUTF(em.getFullTime());
             }  
         }  

       file.close();

     }catch(IOException e1){
         System.out.println("Cant save");
     }  
}
```

Opening file on my computer and all data is recorded and saved.

**Problem is: I cannot get data from file**

Here is my `getFromFile` method:

```
   public void getFromFile(){
    RandomAccessFile file = null;
    try {
        file = new  RandomAccessFile("employees.dat", "rw");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
    while ( file.getFilePointer() < file.length() ){ 

          Employee em = new Employee();

                System.out.println("Saving");
                em.setPps(file.readUTF());
                em.setName(file.readUTF());
                em.setSurname(file.readUTF());
                em.setGender(file.readBoolean());
                em.setDep(file.readUTF());
                em.setSalary(file.readInt());
                em.setFulltime(file.readBoolean());  
                list.add( em );

    }
         file.close();
         }catch(IOException e1){
             System.out.println("Cant save");
             e1.printStackTrace();
         }  
}
```

My JFileChooser for getting from file:

```
    openItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");

        fileChooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Action");

          }
        });

        int status = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

          File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
          getFromFile();

          System.out.println(selectedFile.getParent());
          System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
        } else if (status == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
          System.out.println("calceled");

        }

      }
});
```

Console shows me System.out.println("Saving");, and then System.out.println("Cant save"); . Seems to me that everything should work, however file is empty and nothing new appear in my program.

Here is following exception coming:

```
 java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:399)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:592)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readUTF(RandomAccessFile.java:921)
```

Comment: Instead of printing your own error message, you should use `e1.printStackTrace()` to see what the problem actually is.

Comment: Thank you. I will update my post now.

Comment: I'm confused, how does `save` know what file you selected in `saveFileDialog`?  It's just saving the file in the current working dirctory

Comment: You're calling `em.setPps(file.readUTF());` twice when you read the file, which is probably going to throw things off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "core" problem is likely here...

```
System.out.println("Saving");
em.setPps(file.readUTF());
em.setPps(file.readUTF());
em.setName(file.readUTF());
em.setSurname(file.readUTF());
em.setGender(file.readBoolean());
em.setDep(file.readUTF());
em.setSalary(file.readInt());
em.setFulltime(file.readBoolean());
```

You're calling `setPps` twice.

Also, there is no collation between what you select using the `JFileChooser` and where the file is getting written to/read from

If we take a quick look at the read/write operations we can see the doubl read operation

```
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Write                            | Read                                |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| file.writeUTF(em.getPps());      | em.setPps(file.readUTF());          |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| file.writeUTF(em.getName());     | em.setPps(file.readUTF());          |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| file.writeUTF(em.getSurname());  | em.setName(file.readUTF());         |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| file.writeUTF(em.getGender());   | em.setSurname(file.readUTF());      |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| file.writeUTF(em.getDep());      | em.setGender(file.readBoolean());   |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| file.writeInt(em.getSalary());   | em.setDep(file.readUTF());          |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| file.writeUTF(em.getFullTime()); | em.setSalary(file.readInt());       |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|                                  | em.setFulltime(file.readBoolean()); |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

There's also a disparity between what you're writing and what you're reading

For example, you write the gender using `file.writeUTF(em.getGender());`, but you read it using `em.setGender(file.readBoolean());`

You should probably be using `file.writeBoolean(em.getGender());`

> If it saving to the file properly via my JFileChooser, does it mean that there is collation between them?

Let's take a look at your `saveFileDialog` method

```
private void saveFileDialog(){

    fileChooser = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("employees.dat"));
    disableTextField(fileChooser.getComponents());

    fileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File("employees.dat"));
    fileChooser.setDialogTitle("File to save");

    int userSelection = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
    if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File fileToSave = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        save();
        System.out.println("Save as file: " + fileToSave.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

You create a local variable called `fileToSave` which holds (I presume the directory you want the file saved in), but it only has context to this method, no one else can use

So, your method should read...

```
private void saveFileDialog(){
    save();
}
```

and it would basically achieve the same result

I'd also consider using something like [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) which would probably make your life a lot easier

Comment: Thank you, I got rid of calling steps twice, but still the same problem. If it saving to the file properly via my JFileChooser, does it mean that there is collation between them?

Comment: But "how" does the `save` method know where to save the file?  You never pass that information to the method

Comment: I just go where I want to save my file, and save manually it in my folder for this application. And the open the file there and all data is saved.

Comment: Since you're completely ignoring the results from the `JFileChooser` why have it anyway? It's just causing confusion in your code

Comment: For this moment I am calling setPps only one time. And I am not sure, but why I have boolean and string together when reading and writing gender, because in my Employee class I have the following: `public String getGender() {
         return gender ? "Male":"Female"; 
       } 
  
  public void setGender(boolean gender) {
      this.gender = gender;      
    } `

Comment: @Alex Well, that's not confusing at all, the fact is, you've written a `String` but are trying to read a boolean ... how do you think that's going to end?

Comment: Sorry about misunderstanding about JFileChooser, but I thought that I need to just put JFileChooser without any directories declared and then just go by myself where I want to save my file. or the is another problem of it?

Comment: But the program cant allow me to write the `file.writeBoolean(em.getGender());`, because of this line `public String getGender() { return gender ? "Male":"Female"; }` Should then I change this methods in the Employee class?

Comment: @Alex It would be more consistent

Comment: Thank you, I will try to improve everything a little bit later and then let you know. You help is very appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure is it convenient or not, but it what I did:  `public String getGender() {
         return gender ? "Male":"Female"; 
       } 
  
  public void setGender(String str) {
      this.gender = str != null; 
    }`

Comment: Now it is opening, but every one record is showing twice. I just wonder can I convert in some another way `public void setGender(boolean gender)`, that I could write `readUTF`

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell, but between write and read, you don't seem to be removing any pre-existing records from the `List`.

Comment: okey, how can I do it? do I need to create separate method or it is better to do in reading form file method?

Comment: Well, when you read the file, I'd either create a new instance of the `list` or simply call `removeAll` on it